# OC4J server application is not starting

Tags: java, spring, servlet-3.0, oc4j

Deployed a spring based application to OC4J but getting the below error,

This application got installed successfully but there is some problem in starting the server

This is web.xml used and this application is working fine in other server,

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.app.config.MyConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/starter</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

This application got installed successfully but there is some problem in starting the server
This is the servlet error occuring in server,

```
app: Servlet error 


javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet 'SpringDispatcher'. Servlet class org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    not found in web-application app


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpApplication.servletClassNotFound(HttpApplication
    .java:5062) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpApplication.findServlet(HttpApplication.java:5028
    ) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpApplication.findServlet(HttpApplication.java:4930
    ) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpApplication.getDefaultDispatcher(HttpApplication
    .java:3754) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpApplication.getRequestDispatcher(HttpApplication
    .java:3447) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpApplication.getRequestDispatcher(HttpApplication
    .java:2741) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler
    .java:775) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler
    .java:458) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.serveOneRequest(HttpRequestHandler
    .java:226) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:127) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].server.http.HttpRequestHandler.run(HttpRequestHandler.java:116) 


    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260) 


    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.procClientSocket(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:234) 


    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler.access$700(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:29) 


    at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketAcceptHandler$AcceptHandlerHorse.run(ServerSocketAcceptHandler.java:879) 


    at com.evermind[Oracle Containers for J2EE 10g (10.1.3.5.0) ].util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor
    .java:303) 


    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: why you defined dispatcher servlet mapping twise in xml & url . try instead this <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

Comment: I would go about and check whether org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet is actually in the classpath. I do not know much about oc4j in particular. You do not say much about the other server you have successfully deployed this application to. If that was from within your IDE then it would be useful to check the scoping of your third-party dependencies, i.e. check that they are compile scoped and not provided or similar.

Comment: It is working in tomcat server and integrated with IDE but the OC4J is not within IDE.